# What is the meaning of 'compel'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading a book and found a sentence which wasn't able to understand:

> The Pensées is simply the compelling "Thoughts" of mathematician, physicist, and religious thinker Blaise Pascal.

To [**compel**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compel?s=ts) means to force. But I was thinking, is that what it really means in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used as an adjective, **compelling** is related to **compel**, has a slightly different meaning. From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compelling):

> **compelling** - adjective `\kəm-ˈpe-liŋ\`
>
> 1. very interesting : able to capture and hold your attention
> 2. capable of causing someone to believe or agree
> 3. strong and forceful : causing you to feel that you must do something

In the paragraph you are asking about, it is likely the second definition that is being used; it is saying how *The Pensées*, a book written by *Blaise Pascal*, is very good at *causing you to believe* the theories he is proposing. (Though, it could just as easily be that the book is able to *hold your attention*, both definitions would fit in this case).

Comment: Not necessarily convincing. They compel your attention -- you can't stop paying attention -- but you may or may not be convinced by them. Sort of like Fox News.